# Set the readonly property defined by the system using KVC, is it a private method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview, xib

When I'm building multiple TabelViewCell views with Xib, I don't want to write identfier as static, and this Xib contains multiple Cell types.

However,TableView does not have a method for registering identfier against UINib subclasses, if we use the method provided by the system.

`- (void)registerNib:(nullable UINib *)nib forCellReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);`

I tried to use this method for dynamic identfier registration. But by default it only reads the first View in my Xib.

So I used the following method for dynamic NIb identfier Settings

    `YZHPhoneContactCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifierID];
    if (cell == nil) {
        UINib* nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"YZHPhoneContactCell" bundle:nil];
        cell = [[nib instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:cellType];
        [cell setValue:identifierID forKey:@"reuseIdentifier"];
        }`

I can run normally in this way, but I do not know whether this will belong to the private method of calling the system and affect my App Appstore audit.

Or if you have any better method for dynamically registering Nib multiple sub-view identifier, please tell me. Thank you

Comment: Please, keep in mind that I didn't give this a ton of thought... but when you create your cell like this, it comes back as an instance of the `YZHPhoneContactCell` class, right? If you have source code for this class, you could simply override `reuseIdentifier` getter, couldn't you? Or make it publicly read-write.